# Function in C not returning anything when it's supposed to return int

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Function returns value without return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644860/function-returns-value-without-return-statement)

what is the return value of the function that returns int, but isn't returning anything explicitly.

For instance output of

```
    int fun()
    {
            printf("\ncrap");
    }


    void main()
    {
            printf("\n return value of fun %d", fun());
    }
```

The output I am getting is :

```
  crap
  return value of fun 1
```

Does this depend on compiler I am using ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @Tom...i m using gcc version 4.6.1

Comment: The answer is whatever's in the eax register, I had to add __asm { mov eax, eax; } at the end of the function in order to get it to compile on VC++2010. To get a value of 1 is strange as I would have thought it would have been the return value from the printf("\ncrap") call, which would have been 5.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a return value in fun() function, so the value returned is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

It might be returning whatever's in the EAX register, which is probably unreliable without an explicit return value:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4644913/375399

Answer (score -1):

It depends on compiler.
That's my output, for your information

compiler: i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2

```
crap
return value of fun 0
```