# Control flow reaches end of function

Tags: c, gcc, clang, undefined-behavior

I stumbled upon this behaviour while helping a friend with his homework.

```
#include "stdio.h"
int f(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    n * f(n-1);
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", f(5));
    return 0;
}
```

Given this piece of code, `gcc-5.4.0-r3 (Gentoo)` returns `1` when compiled with any optimization level. What I find most astonishing is though that gcc *compiles without warnings*. Only using `-Wall` it issues a "control flow may reach end of non-void function" warning.

`clang` is a bit more interesting. It generates `0` when compiled without optimizations, but `1` when compiled with optimizations. Contrary to gcc, clang warns the user about the possible control flow error.

According to the C89 standard, this is undefined behaviour. I suspect that gcc (and clang with optimizations) propagate the innermost factorial return to the top, because when the constant changes, so does the return value.

Can someone explain what exactly is happening?

Comment: On Intel, generally the function return is placed in the `ax` register. So without an explicit return statement, you get what was last placed in `ax`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644860/function-returns-value-without-return-statement/4644913

Comment: Just curious about why you want to interpret undefined behaviour. You cannot rely on the behaviour, so why the analysis?

Comment: Compile to asm and check the code. Ultimately that will tell you what is happing *in this instance* (and not-at-all anything useful beyond that).

Comment: @StephanLechner I'm interested in the compiler internals that lead to this specific behavior.

Comment: huh, `gcc` warns too: `a.c:4:7: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
a.c:5:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]` Did you ask for warnings (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`)?

Comment: @ikegami I misclarified: gcc without and warning flags reports no warnings.

Comment: Yeah, and my phone makes no sound when I leave mute on. Why is that surprising???