# I cant understand the logic in my C program

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int factorial(int value){
    if(value == 0){
        value * factorial(value - 1);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int value = 0;
    printf("The factorial of %d of %d",value, factorial(value));
}
```

> I got an output of

```
The factorial of 0 is -1
```

Can anyone explain why I got -1 ???

I tried to watch a few videos on this but I didn't get the answer

Explain the logic of this if possible?

Thank you

Comment: 1. You're not returning the value from your function.

2. In the line `if(value == 0){` you probably meant `if(value > 0){`

Comment: Compile with the `-Wall` option. You'll get two warnings [that you should fix]: "value computed is not used" and "control reaches end of non-void function"

Comment: @AntonCurmanschii well I know that I made a mistake in it its actually not even a complete factorial program I wondered what will happen if I didn't return anything

Comment: You are invoking UB if you do not return anything. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58424449/5550963

Comment: Another UB is your function is overflowing if you pass `17` into it, because you are returning value larger than `MAX_INT` (maximum signed integer).

Comment: @Codebegginer see my answer, I know its a bit complex for beginner but what it boils down is that your processor is using same "memory" for `value` and `return`.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple problems with `factorial`:  It's never returning anything, and it's recursing when `0` is passed to it (that should be the basis case and should return `1`).
Try this:

```
int factorial(int value) {
    if (value == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return value * factorial(value - 1);
}
```

Comment: Should also add to the if statement " || value ==1".

Comment: @George It's not needed for correctness, but it would speed up small cases.  I wanted to keep to the original intent as closely as possible.

Comment: I guess that's fair. I imagined he was eventually going to change value to be something other than 0 (I hope).  I will remember this for answering future questions!

Comment: Well I wanted wrote the program with a few mistakes I didn't return the value and || value ==1 must have been used and I checked this with a few other values then it gives the same value in return
I guessed that if the function doesn't have a program in to run then it will simply give the same value which it received in return
ex : value = 10 // in my program
     output is 10 // giving the same value

Comment: I'm just trying to know how it works by making it kind of wrong sorry if wasted the time
I didn't intend the question to help me with the factorial program I intended it to know how it works

Comment: @Codebegginer read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58424449/5550963

Comment: Hey its OPs problem as well, but use at least `long`, if you pass `17` you are invoking UB.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone explain why I got -1 ???

This is undefined behavior, but possible answer is that compiler is using same register

```
    .text
    .globl  factorial
    .type   factorial, @function
factorial:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp    #   
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16 
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  #,  
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp   #,
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)  # value, value
# fact.c:14:    if(value == 0) value *factorial (value - 1); so if value != 0 execute these 2 lines
    cmpl    $0, -4(%rbp)    #, value
    jne .L2 #, jump to L2 if not equal to 0
# fact.c:14:    if(value == 0)  value *fact (value -1); execute next 4 lines if value == 0
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax  # value, tmp90
    subl    $1, %eax    #, _1
    movl    %eax, %edi  # _1,
    call    factorial    #   
.L2:
# fact.c:17: }
    nop 
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret 
    .cfi_endproc
```

So register `eax` is used for return value, thus if you look this assembly snippet:

```
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax  # value, tmp90
    subl    $1, %eax    #, _1
    movl    %eax, %edi  # _1,
    call    factorial    #
```

You see that `value` have been moved into `%eax`, than `1` is subtracted and `factorial` is called again in which case its `value` is not `0` thus it will exit.

> EAX: The accumulator. This register typically stores return values from functions.

from [this page](https://arvindsraj.wordpress.com/2013/01/12/x86-registers-register-conventions-and-calling-conventions/).