# Function return value optimization?

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

I am writing my own programming language, which for various reasons, compiles to C. (one of which is that I know little-to-nothing about assembly).

I have a question about how a compiler (say GCC or Clang)  might optimize returning a value from a function. Let's say I have code like this:

```
int FUNC()
{
    int A = 3;
    return A;
}

int main()
{
    int B = FUNC();
}
```

My understanding is that you'd expect the variable A to be copied to B upon return from FUNC (which could be expensive if A and B are structs). Would a compiler recognize that in this case B can just point to wherever A is and that a copy is not needed?

What if main() looks like this:?

```
int main()
{
    int C;
    C = FUNC();
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: This whole program can be optimized into a `NOP`, as it does not do anything observable.

Comment: It's not as expensive as you think and you have to copy the value because it's mutable. If you want a pointer, use a pointer

Comment: This is called "copy elision" by the way. In recent C++ versions, it's no longer merely an optimization; it's mandated by the spec https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision IDK about C though.

Comment: @Alexander C doesn't have copy/move constructors, so copy elision is irrelevant. Of course the compiler is still free to make any optimizations that don't change observable behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically two cases.  (1) The return value is something other than a struct, and (2) the return value is a struct.

For case (1), the return value is typically in a register -- it used to always be r0, or maybe f0 in the case of floating-point returns, or maybe r0+r1 in the case of `long int` returns.

In that case, when you have something like

```
int a()
{
    return 3;
}

int b()
{
    return a();
}
```

the compiler basically compiles `b()` to some code that calls function `a`, and that's it.  Function `a` returns its value in whichever register `int`-valued functions return, and that's just where it needs to be for function `b` to return it, so there's nothing else to do; the value is already where it belongs.  And therefore, at least in this case, there's no extra copying involved.

(This can also lead to situations where seemingly "wrong" code works anyway, and thus this Frequently-Asked Question: [Function returns value without return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644860/function-returns-value-without-return-statement).)

But then, in your function `main` where you did `int B = b()`, then yes, there may be a "copy" from the return register to `B`'s location.  (Although, these days, a smart compiler may remember that "for now, `r0` is `B`".)

For structs, on the other hand (that is, case 2), and especially for large ones, the compiler typically passes an extra, hidden argument which is a pointer to the location in the caller where the return value should go.  That is, if you have

```
struct largestruct bb();

int main()
{
    struct largestruct B;
    B = bb();
}
```

it will be compiled more or less as if you had written

```
void bb(struct largestruct *);

int main()
{
    struct largestruct B;
    bb(&B);
}
```

So if you then have

```
extern struct largestruct aa();

struct largestruct bb()
{
    return aa();
}
```

It will probably be compiled as if it were written

```
extern void aa(struct largestruct *);

void bb(struct largestruct *__retp)
{
    aa(__retp);
}
```

And, again, it's more or less true that "the pointer points to the right place, and no copy is needed".

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is free to write things like:

```
int tmp = a + b;
int c = tmp;
```

`tmp` will get optimized out.

Your function will first of all get optimized similarly by not allocating `A` but just returning 3, taken from read-only memory (inlined together with the machine code).

Function inlining works similarly too, the whole function call in this case will get replaced by 3.

Now if we add a side effect like printing, `printf("%d", B);`, your whole code gets optimized to assembler like this "pseudo code assembler":

- move 3 into register x
- move address of the string literal "%d" into register y
- call printf(x,y)

In real x86 asm that would be something like:

```
mov     esi, 3
mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
call    printf
```

The variables `A` `B` and the function are all optimized away.

Answer (score 0):

Good compilers go beyond the optimizations you suggest. Apple Clang 11 with `-O3` compiles your `main` routine to:

```
_main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

Thus the compiler has gone beyond your suggestions of coalescing `A` and `B`; it has removed them entirely.

If we include `<stdio.h>` and insert `printf("%d\n", B);` in `main`, it is compiled to:

```
_main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
    movl    $3, %esi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    callq   _printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

Now `A` and `B` are not completely removed, but they have been reduced to a single immediate constant in an instruction.