# how this function return a value with out a return statement. can someone explain the logic behind it

Tags: c, return-value, return-type, function-definition

The output of the below code is `660 44 352 660` . My question is how does the `element()` function return the value of `k` without a `return` statement. Can someone explain the logic behind it

```
#include <stdio.h>

int k = 9;

int element(int a, int b) {
    k = k + (a * b);
}
    
int main() {
    int a = 12, b = 5, c = 7;
    a = element(c, b);
    b = element(a, c);
    c = element(a, c);
    printf("%d ", k);
    printf("%d ", a);
    printf("%d ", b);
    printf("%d ", c);
}
```

Comment: Please see [Function returns value without return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644860/function-returns-value-without-return-statement)

Comment: In addition to the answers and comments: 
Your code is wrong at multiple levels: - modifying a global variable in a function (bad coding practice),- no return statement for a non void function (extremely bad coding practice, for me this is plain wrong), - using return values from a non void function without return statement (invokes undefined behaviour)

Answer (score 2):

These statements

```
a = element(c,b);
b = element(a,c);
c = element(a,c);
```

invoke undefined behavior because the function returns nothing but the caller (main) tries to use its value.

From the C Standard (J.2 Undefined behavior)

> — The } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the
> function call is used by the caller (6.9.1).

On the other hand the function deals with the file scope variable `k`

```
int k = 9;
int element (int a,int b){
k = k+(a*b)
}
```

So this statement in ,main

```
print("%d ",k);
```

outputs the current value of the file scope variable `k` that in general can be indeterminate.

The output can be expected when for example the generated assembler code uses register AX or EAX to load the value of the variable `k`. This register is used in assembler to return a value from a called function. Nevertheless it's a matter of chance.

Comment: Perhaps re-word for better clarity.  "invoke undefined behavior because the function returns nothing" **and** the caller uses the return value.  Returning nothing, by itself, is not UB.  It was unclear to me that the code and statement made that clear.

Comment: but the value of the variable c and variable k are equal how the value of  variable c changes how?

Comment: @ShivaSurya.S It can be due to the generated assembler code when the function loads the value of the variable k in the register AX or EAX that is usually used to return a value from a function in assembler.

Comment: @ShivaSurya.S undefined behaviour is undefined. Undefined behaviour includes "apparently working fine".

Comment: @ShivaSurya.S it's all there in the link.

Answer (score 1):

k is a global variable.
It is accessible (and modifiable) from anywhere is the code.
In your case, it is modified at each call of the `element` function.

You actually have an error in your code: the element function is defined as `int element (int a,int b)`, which mean it takes 2 `int` as arguments, and return an `int`, but you do not return anything, which is undefined behavior, meaning anything could happens (mostly bad things).

You should use compiler options to raise more warnings and errors to help you.
For example with `gcc`, you can use `-Wall` to start with.

Comment: IIRC, not returning anything is _not_ UB - still bad coding. It is the caller using the "non"-return value that is UB.  Had OP's code been `element(c,b);` and not `a = element(c,b);`, it would be OK.  Good idea to enable all warnings.

Comment: can we predict that undefined behavior without compiling the code?

Comment: Sure we can _predict_, but UB is not specified to be consistent - it is _undefined_, so we might be wrong in our prediction.

Comment: When a function returns a value with a `return` statement, this value is stored in a place where the caller expects to retrieve it. This *place* is determined by the calling convention for your target architecture, a collection of rules called the ABI (application binary interface). In most current systems, the return value of type `int` is passed back to the caller in a specific register (eg: `%eax` for intel processors). In your case, the register happens to contain the updated value of `k`, so the program seems to work as expected, but by pure chance.