# bug in compilation of simple c program

Tags: c

the code:

```
/* find the greatest common divisor of two integers */
#include <stdio.h>
int gcd(int p, int q);

void main()
{
    int u,v,g;
    printf("Enter two numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&u,&v);
    g=gcd(u,v);
    printf("Greatest Common Divisor of %d and %d is %d",u,v,g);
}

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    int m;
    m=a%b;
    if(m==0)
        return(b);
    else
        gcd(b,m);
}
```

is working properly on https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

the code is NOT working on macosx/ sierra with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
since the value of the returned variable 'b' does not get assigned to the variable 'g' in line 'g=gcd(u,v);'

'g' always gets the value of 0.

how could this issue be fixed on the mac?

could not find a workaround on stackoverflow.

Comment: Maybe it is because you forgot the `return` before the call to `gcb()` in the second last line?

Comment: `gcd(b,m);` -> `return gcd(b,m);`. `return` only exits one level of recursion, not all of them. Your compiler should've warned you, compile with `-Wall -Wextra` to enable warnings. (`-std=c++20 -pedantic-errors` is also useful).

Comment: Also two small things you should change: Please do not use `return(b)`, use just `return b` instead. It is not a function call. And also the main function return `int`, not `void`. You don't have to write `return 0` in the main function since C99 anymore, but you should make the type `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The last line in `gcd` needs to have a `return`.

```
if(m==0)
    return(b);
else
    return gcd(b,m);
```

Comment: that's interesting! does this have to do with c standards?
1st) in the onlinegdb platform this last return is not needed, and
2nd) why isn't the else supposed to contain a recursive call only?
 the recursion is stopped only in the if(m==0) statement and then returning to os?

Comment: That last return *is* needed. It's just luck that it works without the `return`. If you don't return, it's undefined behavior. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644860/function-returns-value-without-return-statement