# Why it returns max anyway?

Tags: c++, return

A minute ago, I wrote a function without return of finding max value in C++,

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int myItem(int x, int y, int z)
{
    int a = std::max(x, y);
    int b = std::max(a, z);
    // return b;
}

int main()
{
    cout << myItem(2, 5, 16);
}
```

But, why it returns max value without `return`?

On the Windows, g++ (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function returns value without return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644860/function-returns-value-without-return-statement). Strictly speaking this is a C question, but the answer is the same in C++: undefined behavior is undefined. _Anything_ can happen, including the compiler accidentally doing "the right thing" (for now)

Comment: *But, why it returns max value without return?* -- This is undefined behavior.  Your compiler should have warned you that you are not returning a value from the function.

Comment: **Undefined behavior** can do surprising things.  Even worse, sometimes they can appear to behave in a desirable way.  Note: on my machine, your code crashes.  I got lucky.  You got unlucky.

Comment: Undefined behavior means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely on the output of a program that has UB. The program may just crash. [Why does flowing off the end of a non-void function without returning a value not produce a compiler error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-does-flowing-off-the-end-of-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-no) **Always enable all warnings.**

Comment: What if you add `int c = std::min(a,z);` before the commented-out `return`?

Comment: It's undefined behaviour but it'll just be that a certain register is used for the return value, if you don't add a return the register may still contain the result of the last function call which in this case happens to be the right answer

Comment: Totally unrelated: Your build tools are nearly a decade out of date. [Here is a path to updated tools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/4581301) along with an easy way to keep the tools up to date and access to an impressive repository of pre-built libraries for those build tools.